# ajax call to web method not working in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm trying to set up a very simple web method call in VS 2010, and failing miserably. The exact same setup works in VS2008 and I can't figure out where the difference is. The code is as follows:

test.aspx ajax call (I also tried without the localhost):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#btnAjax").click(function ()
    {
        var testData = "test";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/test.aspx/Test",
            data: JSON.stringify({ test: testData }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg)
            {
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function (xhr, err)
            {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

test.aspx.cs (breakpoint shows the method is never reached):

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Test(string test)
    {
        return "xyz";
    }
```

web.config (I took those from the VS2008 version that works):

```
<modules>
<remove name="ScriptModule"/>
<add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
<remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
<remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
<remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
<remove name="ScriptResource"/>
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</handlers>
```

The ready state returned is always 0 and the response text empty; firebug shows the correct data is posted, the response tab shows the page html; I've not had to use the firebug debugger before, so perhaps there's something more I should look at. Console/Net are enabled but I did not see anything glaringly obvious.

I searched a lot but can't find anything that helps or that I haven't tried already. In a word, I don't know where else to look...

Perhaps one pointer might be the fact that I initially tried to implement a WCF service but it kept failing with 'authentication failed' - from what I read it has to with IIS setup, but none of the posts I found worked. Since it does not have to be WCF, I eventually thought I go back to basics, i.e. this simple web method. I don't know how I could verify if it's an authentication issue or something else. What makes me think this is not is the fact that the VS2008 version works with the exact same server.

Any suggestions are massively appreciated.

Comment: what is the error ? what version of jQuery?

Comment: thanks for the quick response - that's the problem, the error just says ready state 0, no response text; the jquery version is 1.8.3 and 1.10.2, but it should not make a difference since it works in VS 2008

Comment: I've tested your code and it works in vs2008 and vs2010! I started from empty website and didn't need to change anything in config

Comment: Is this a web application (File --> New --> Project --> ASP.NET Web Application) or a web site (File --> New --> Web Site)?

Comment: thanks for your comments and the time to test - it's a web application and i'm still getting virtually no joy; after starting (again) with a completely new project and adding additional user permissions in iis, it's at least working in ie but nowhere else - some posts indicate the browser difference may have to do with the additional OPTION request sent by ff (and perhaps others), so i'll try a few of those suggestions...

@Michael B - the fact it's working for you strengthens my suspicion that it's somehow connected to the environment

Answer (score 0):

got it to work... finally... posting it as an answer in case someone else runs into this

the problem was the call needs async: false, or - at least in my case - it fails on most browsers; it doesn't make sense to me though as to why, so i'll post a separate question, hopefully someone can explain